# Python Memory optimization

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, memory, memory-management

I am trying to generate a 100K x 100K pixel image of the Mandelbrot set. I can do a 10K x 10K image in about 2 minutes (I'm on my laptop) but I can't really go further without a MemoryError. My question is there any way to optimize the code to be able to handle such a large image. I don't know too much about python optimization, and I am sure there are better ways to do it.

```
from PIL import Image

Px = 100000 #this is the size of the image
Py = 100000

img = Image.new( 'RGB', (Px,Py), "white")
pixels = img.load()


Xfactor = Px
Yfactor = Py
Zoom = float(33333) #I predicted this to be the zoom level, for 10K x 10K it's around 3,333-2,500

def TestPoint(val):
    n = 0
    for i in range(100):
        k = n**2 + val
        n = k
        if abs(k.real) > 100:
            return False
    return True

def BuildScreen():
    for j in range(Xfactor):
        for i in range(Yfactor):  #This loop goes through every pixel in the image and checks if it's in the set. I think theres a much better way to do this but I don't know-how.
            if TestPoint(complex((i/Zoom)-(Xfactor/(Zoom*2)),(j/Zoom)-(Yfactor/(Zoom*2)))):
                pixels[i,j] = (0, 0, 0)
    

BuildScreen()
img.save("mandelbrot.png")
```

Comment: 100K * 100K is 1000000 Megapixels.  That's too big to fit in most memory.

Comment: What do you intend to do with that image?

Comment: @MarkRansom You're factor 100 too large.

Comment: @superbrain right you are.  You'd think I'd know how to count zeros by now.  So it's 10000 Megapixels, which is still quite a lot.  I believe a Mandelbrot set will require a floating point value at each pixel.

Comment: @superbrain It's not going to be used for anything really, it's just for proof of concept and just looking at.

Comment: @MarkRansom The simplest output, which is what the OP is doing, is a black-and-white image. So it *could* be done with one bit per pixel, which would be 1.25 Gb. My seven years old *phone* has more memory :-)

Comment: @Pixel_256 Where are you going to look at it, though? On the computer? Printed as a poster? Btw, it might be good/nice to include a small version of the image in the question.

Comment: @superbrain but notice that the code uses a PIL image in `'RGB'` mode, which takes at least 3 bytes per pixel.  Probably more.

Comment: @MarkRansom That's why I said *could* :-)

Comment: @MarkRansom Hmm, with an on-the-fly PNG encoder which takes an iterable of pixels, 0.06 bits per pixel might be possible even if the encoder holds the whole image in memory. I just tried their code with 400x400 and reduced the result to two colors, ended up with a 1.1 kB PNG file.

Comment: @Pixel_256 Could you split image into hundred 10Kx10K pieces to generate and save them separately?